# There are two functions in a code, I want to disable the edit for the outer function. How to disable it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ide

I am implementing an online coding environment and in the starter template there is two functions(the functions are given below). I want to disable the outer function so that, no user can edit the outer function name while coding. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

`

```
function main() {

    console.log("outer Function");

    function Add(){
        
        console.log("inner Function");
        
    }
    return Add()    
}
main()
```

`

Comment: It probably depends on the IDE

Comment: This is a very unique edge-case. What's your reason for doing this? Maybe there's another solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.